# Show the form data on the page without loading

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

When the comment form posts I want to show the latest comment at the top without reloading the page. The comment is stored to the database but with my code, I am not being able to show the comment. I saw some tutorial doing `.push` and `. unshift` but here it says `unshift` function not defined.

```
comments = [];

onSubmit = () => {
    let data = {
        id: this.route.snapshot.params.id,
        comment: this.form.comment,
        user: this._tokenService.getUser()

    };

    this._eventservice.postComment(data).subscribe(
        res => {
            this.comments.unshift(data.comment)
            this.form.comment = null;
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: Why isn't onSubmit defined as a method? Do that, and post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Also, don't paraphrase the error. Post the complete and exact error you get.